# Windows 10 Registry cannot deleted by code

Tags: c#, windows, console, registry, windows-10

I developed one console program in c# to test registry (ADD/EDIT/DELETE). 
I got success to add registry as well update same registry.
but I face problem while delete same registry.
I used following code to delete registry.

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKey(@"Software\MyRegis");
```

this works fine with windows 7, windows 8 and windows 8.1 but not working in windows 10.

can anyone know why and what should be the solution.
thank you in advance.

Comment: It worked well in Windows 10 RTM, I just created a SubKey and used this method to delete it. If you have added SubKey under Software\MyRegis\, use DeleteSubKeyTree method

Comment: Console.WriteLine(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\MyRegis").ToString()); this return path well in win7 but getting error in win10

Comment: Here is my result(Ensure that removed Software\MyRegis SubKey in Registry Editor): Firstly, Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\MyRegis"); Then CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\MyR‌​egis"), on both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10, got "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception, this is expected result

Comment: yaa but working fine with win7

Comment: Did you try running the console app as admin?

Comment: yes because i know this kind of OS level operations needs admin rights